React problem with setting data into constant
I have piece of code to put image URL from server part into JSON payload. I'll show you what it looks like in code and what output gives the browser:
const url = `${apiUrl}/api/image/${barcode}`;
console.log("variable url:", url);
setPhotoUrl(`${apiUrl}/api/image/${barcode}`);
console.log("photoUrl when i put full url string:", photoUrl);
setPhotoUrl(url);
console.log("photoUrl when i put url variable inside:", photoUrl);

Output from browser:
browser output
Why this url don't want to set in photoUrl constant even if it's working in url variable?

Calling setPhotoUrl does not change the value in the local variable photoUrl, so your log statement can only ever log out the previous state. Instead, setPhotoUrl asks react to rerender the component. When that render happens, a new local variable will be created, also named photoUrl, but code from your old render has no access to that.

So, what you find the best solution for this problem @NicholasTower?

The problem you described is just a logging problem. If you want to log out the new value, you can do that with console.log(url). If you want to verify that your component is rerendering, put a log statement in the body of the component, such as right after the line where you create photoUrl. const [photoUrl, setPhotoUrl] = useState(''); console.log('rendering with', photoUrl).
